# How to opencart 2.3.0.2 version into free modules add?

Tags: opencart

How to open cart 2.3.0.2 version into free modules add?

1. I try to free model
2. go to admin -> design -> layout -> add(module)

please send processing step by step explain

Comment: you want to add templates in opencart ?

Comment: no, i try to only free extension modules add into administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the file and ftp it to your cart (or copy it to your cart directory, if you are running it locally).  The module will be laid out in a way that matches your cart, so copy the catalog folder from the module to the catalog folder in your cart, admin folder to admin folder, etc.  Then you will have to go to admin->extensions->extensions, select modules and install your module.

Answer (score 0):

- admin pane  `>` Extensions `>` Extension installer
- Click on the upload button `>` Select the  .zip file and click “OK”
- After clicking “OK” your extension will be uploaded and a “success” message should appear. `>` Now your module should be visible in Extensions
- Modules. After locating it in the Module list just click the install button (“ + ” sign) >
- The final step of the installation process is to apply the changes we have just made. In order to do so, go to Extensions `>` Modifications and click the Refresh sign at the upper right corner of the page.

Comment: admin pane > extensions > extension installer > click upload button > here .zip file not support